# ¿Cómo posicionar botón en la parte inferior dentro de tag <div>?

Tags: css, html5

Nesecito posicionar un boton en la parte inferior izquierda de una , he intentado varias cosas pero no funciona...

Codigo HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="flot-chart dashboard-chart" id="charting">
            <div class="flot-chart-content" id="flot-dashboard-chart"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div aling="left">
        **<div class="top-left">
            <input type="button" id="fullScreen" name="fullScreem" value="Full Screen" onclick="PantallaCompleta()" class="btn" />
        </div>**
    </div>
</div>
```

Codigo CSS

```
  .btn {
        background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 2px 15px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 12px;
        position: absolute;
    }

   .ToLeft{
        float: left;
        left: 90%;
        z-index: 0;
        position: absolute;
    }
```

El boton deberia verse en la parte inferior del grafico..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: .ToLeft?? esa clase no figura en tu html...

Answer (score 1):

position:absolute y float no trabajan bien juntos, considera que tienen distintos puntos de referencia para situar los elementos, (aquí tienes un [enlace](https://trisfera.com/ejemplosretos/position_float/)).
Si lo que quieres es que el botón se situe justo en la esquina inferior derecha/izquierda de la gráfica, una de las posibilidades que se me ocurren es que elimines la propiedad `position:absolute` y `left:90%`, si el tamaño del container ya tiene un ancho definido (col-md-8 de bootstrap por lo que muestras), desplazarlo con float debería ser suficiente. igualmente, bootstrap te brinda la clase `pull-right` para desplazar el elemento

```
<div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="flot-chart dashboard-chart" id="charting">
            <div class="flot-chart-content" id="flot-dashboard-chart"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <input type="button" id="fullScreen" name="fullScreem" value="Full Screen" onclick="PantallaCompleta()" class="btn" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Por otra parte.. la sintaxis está mal, tienes un div *aling="left"* (debería ser align, y si mal no recuerdo se aplica a elementos de tipo img)

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con esto:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="flot-chart dashboard-chart" id="charting">
            <div class="flot-chart-content" id="flot-dashboard-chart"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; left: 90%; bottom: 0;">
            <input type="button" id="fullScreen" name="fullScreem" value="Full Screen" onclick="PantallaCompleta()" class="btn" />
        </div>
</div>
```

Para que un elemento hijo este dentro de un elemento padre, el elemento padre debe tener la propiedad `position: relative`, esto hace que el hijo este dentro del contenedor padre.